# if the server can find the path to wsgi.py why can't it find settings.py which is in the same directory

Tags: python, django

here is the error log i am getting

```
[Mon Dec 29 20:29:38 2014] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.5.
[Mon Dec 29 20:29:38 2014] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
[Mon Dec 29 20:29:38 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 29 20:30:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=17333): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/rock/webapps/hswcell/HswcellDjango/Hswcell/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Dec 29 20:30:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Dec 29 20:30:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/rock/webapps/hswcell/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
[Mon Dec 29 20:30:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self.load_middleware()
[Mon Dec 29 20:30:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/rock/webapps/hswcell/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Mon Dec 29 20:30:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Mon Dec 29 20:30:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/rock/webapps/hswcell/lib/python2.7/django/conf/__init__.py", line 52, in __getattr__
[Mon Dec 29 20:30:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._setup(name)
[Mon Dec 29 20:30:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/rock/webapps/hswcell/lib/python2.7/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
[Mon Dec 29 20:30:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Mon Dec 29 20:30:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/rock/webapps/hswcell/lib/python2.7/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
[Mon Dec 29 20:30:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Mon Dec 29 20:30:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: Could not import settings 'Hswcell.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named Hswcell.settings
```

if server can find the wsgi.py path can't it find the settings.py file which lies in same directory.

Comment: in wsgi.py, you are one step further or one step lagging in ``Hswcell.settings``

Comment: i just checked, they are both in Hswcell directory

Comment: But those are quite different paths, aren't they? In the Apache settings you use a file path to the wsgi file. But the wsgi file itself uses a Python module path to find settings. Have you modified PYTHONPATH - or `sys.path` - in any way to add `Hswcell` to it?

Comment: yes i did , by modifying wsgi.py like this  -------------------------------import os, sys

sys.path.insert(0,'/home/rock/webapps/hswcell/HswcellDjango/Hswcell')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Hswcell.settings")

Answer (score 0):

finally got rid of the error.

i had trouble adding the settings directory to python path ,
here is how i finally did it

```
Adding to sys.path from httpd.conf

For web applications running on mod_wsgi, the Python module search path can be amended in the httpd.conf file, found in /home/username/webapps/appname/apache2/conf/. The file contains a line like this:

WSGIDaemonProcess app_name processes=5 python-path=/home/username/webapps/app_name:/home/username/webapps/app_name/lib/python2.7 threads=1
```